# c# wpf is there a mouse hover event for ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, combobox, mouseevent

I am trying to update some values while the user hovers over the Items of a ComboBox. An example would be:

[image]

The selected item of this ComboBox is currently 40. But here I would like to have an event to be fired when user moves the mouse pointer over the value of 66. The action I am trying is to dynamically change the font size in another TextBox when user hovers through the numbers inside this ComboBox.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sure you can. Implement a hover method for the `comboBox´s` elements. Just bind the event in XAML and implement the method in your code. By the way, that´s not how SO works. Put some effort in research and try it on your own before asking.

Comment: What is the name of this hover event? Is it myComboBox.Items.CurrentChanging or another thing? And also how can I catch the item that is being under hover currently?

Comment: @alikerimerkan CurrentChanging sounds pretty unlikely based on the name. Mouse events have the word "mouse" in the name. You can look this up on your own. You can google the MSDN documentation, or just look through the properties with intellisense. The events have little lightning bolt icons next to them.

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=c%23%20wpf%20combobox%20element%20mouseover%20event&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW566ar4nXAhVDLlAKHUpcB94QBQgjKAA&biw=1920&bih=949

Just put some effort in it. That´s what programming is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do but if you want to perform some action when the mouse moves over a `ComboBoxItem`, you could use an `ItemContainerStyle` and a `DependencyPropertyDescriptor`:

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd;
private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem cmb = sender as ComboBoxItem;
    dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor
        .FromProperty(IsMouseOverProperty, typeof(ComboBoxItem));
    if (dpd != null)
        dpd.AddValueChanged(cmb, OnIsMouseOver);

}

private void ComboBox_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dpd != null)
        dpd.RemoveValueChanged(cmb, OnIsMouseOver);

}

private void OnIsMouseOver(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem cmb = sender as ComboBoxItem;
    if (cmb.IsMouseOver)
    {
        //do something...
    }
}
```

---

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ComboBox_Loaded" />
            <EventSetter Event="Unloaded" Handler="ComboBox_Unloaded" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: That helped to respond the events when user hovers over the values of combobox. However I implemented the click events handler like: `cmb.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += OnMouseLeftBtnDown;`. Thanks